# Laravel 5.1 - Standalone EC2 to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-ec2, laravel-5.1

I have a Laravel 5.1 app deployed on a standalone EC2.  I would like to deploy it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  Can I just zip it up and upload it or do I need to deploy everything from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on how you've structured your project, but generally yes, you can zip up your project, put it on the S3 bucket for your EB environment, then deploy it from there during environment creation.

I recommend you do this directly in your project folder using the eb-cli tool from Amazon though. You can keep deploying changes to a local git repo without having to zip and upload the project manually every time, eb-cli does this for you.

It's also likely you'll want to do some customization on the instances after they get created. These can be done through environment variables (safely setting things like api keys, database connection credentials etc) and scripts you put in the .ebextensions folder (for things like putting up modified server config files or installing dependencies as yum packages).